# OneWire DS18B20 getting a temperature in vb.net from a specified sensor

Tags: vb.net

I am a newbie to programming and am rewriting the code on my automatic brewery to move from analog temperature sensing to onewire.

I am struggling to get any joy however, can someone run their brain over this code for me and advise please?  The aim is to get HLT_currenttemp to read what ever the current temperature of the DS18B20 sensor at hltaddress.

```
 Dim owd As com.dalsemi.onewire.container.OneWireContainer
    Dim state As Object
    Dim tc As com.dalsemi.onewire.container.TemperatureContainer
    ' Try
    ' get exclusive use of 1-Wire network
    adapter.beginExclusive(True)
    ' clear any previous search restrictions
    adapter.setSearchAllDevices()
    adapter.targetAllFamilies()
    adapter.setSpeed(com.dalsemi.onewire.adapter.DSPortAdapter.SPEED_REGULAR)
    owd = CreateObject("OWAPI.OneWireContainer28")
    ' retrieve OneWireContainer
    owd.setupContainer(adapter, hltaddress)

    ' cast the OneWireContainer to TemperatureContainer
    tc = DirectCast(owd, com.dalsemi.onewire.container.TemperatureContainer)
    ' read the device
    state = tc.readDevice
    ' extract the temperature from previous read
    tc.doTemperatureConvert(state)
    ' retrieve Temp
    HLT_Currentemp = (Math.Round(tc.getTemperature(state), 2))

    Debug.WriteLine(tc.getTemperature(state))
    ' end exclusive use of 1-Wire net adapter
    adapter.endExclusive()
    'Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(hltaddress)
        ' End Try
```

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

```
' retrieve OneWireContainer
        owd = adapter.getDeviceContainer(hltaddress)
        ' cast the OneWireContainer to TemperatureContainer
        tc = DirectCast(owd, com.dalsemi.onewire.container.TemperatureContainer)
        ' read the device
        state = tc.readDevice
        ' extract the temperature from previous read
        tc.doTemperatureConvert(state)
        ' retrieve Temp
        HLT_Currentemp = (Math.Round(tc.getTemperature(state), 3))
```